# Type hints and expected types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm unsure if this question belongs on Code Review or Stack Overflow.

Another developer told me that I should consider adding type hints to my open source project [WordHoard](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/wordhoard).

I have never used type hints before and the documentation doesn't seem intuitive. So I need to guidance on how to implement this functionality in my code.

I've started looking at adding it some low level code pieces first.

For example:

```py
from typing import AnyStr, Dict

def colorized_text(r: int, g: int, b: int, text: str) -> AnyStr:
    """
    This function provides error messages color.
    For example:
    rgb(255, 0, 0) is displayed as the color red
    rgb(0, 255, 0) is displayed as the color green
    :param r: red color value
    :param g: green color value
    :param b: below color value
    :param text: text to colorized
    :return: string of colorized text
    """
    return f"\033[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{text}\033[0m"
```

Are type hints implemented correctly in the function `colorized_text`?

Here is another code example.

```py
from typing import Optional

temporary_dict_antonyms = {}

def cache_antonyms(word: str) -> [bool, str]:
    item_to_check = word
    if item_to_check in temporary_dict_antonyms.keys():
        values = temporary_dict_antonyms.get(item_to_check)
        return True, list(sorted(set(values)))
    else:
        return False, None

def insert_word_cache_antonyms(word: str, values: list[str]) -> None:
    if word in temporary_dict_antonyms:
        deduplicated_values = set(values) - set(temporary_dict_antonyms.get(word))
        temporary_dict_antonyms[word].extend(deduplicated_values)
    else:
        values = [value.strip() for value in values]
        temporary_dict_antonyms[word] = values
```

How do I implement type hints correctly in the second example?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: First example works, is almost correct, and can be reviewed. Second example needs to be cut away to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am unwilling to believe you meant `.append(values)`. It seems more likely you intended `.extend(values)`, leading to a single flat list of antonyms, rather than a nested list structure.

Comment: @J_H GOOD CATCH!! You found an issue that I didn't know existed.

Comment: @Reinderien I updated the second code example so that it doesn't throw an error now.

Comment: [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/) can help you check if your type hints are correct.

Comment: @Wombatz thanks, I will look into how `mypy` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are type hints implemented correctly in the function `colorized_text`?

Almost; the return type should just be `str`, not `AnyStr`.  `AnyStr` is for when (a) a function can take or return both `str` and `bytes`, (b) there are either multiple `AnyStr` arguments or one (or more) `AnyStr` arguments & an `AnyStr` return type, and (c) all `AnyStr` arguments/return types must be either all `str`s or all `bytes`s when the function is actually called.  A simple example would be a function that take two `str`s or two `bytes` and returns their concatenation; the arguments and return type would then all be `AnyStr`.

Also, you imported `typing.Dict` but don't use it.

> How do I implement type hints correctly in the second example?

First, you need an annotation for `temporary_dict_antonyms`.  It appears to be a dict mapping `str`s to lists of `str`s, so write `temporary_dict_antonyms: dict[str, list[str]] = {}`.

Secondly, to annotate a tuple (such as in `cache_antonyms`'s return type), you need to write  either `tuple[ArgType1, ArgType2]` etc. or `tuple[ArgType, ...]` for a tuple of variable length where all elements are the same type.

Now, `cache_antonyms` can return either a tuple of a `bool` and a `list[str]` or a `bool` and a `None`.  I don't know why you feel the need to return a `bool` when the caller could just check whether the second field is non-`None`, but the simplest way to annotate the return value is `-> tuple[bool, Optional[list[str]]]`.

By the way, I would recommend implementing `cache_antonyms` with a single `dict` query as follows:

```py
def cache_antonyms(word: str) -> tuple[bool, Optional[list[str]]]:
    try:
        values = temporary_dict_antonyms[word]
    except KeyError:
        return (False, None)
    else:
        return (True, sorted(set(values)))  # sorted() already returns a list
```

The annotations on `insert_word_cache_antonyms` are fine, but mypy will likely complain about `set(temporary_dict_antonyms.get(word))`, because the `get()` can return `None`, which is not a valid input to `set()`; change it to `set(temporary_dict_antonyms[word])`.

Additional comments:

- If you want your code to run on Pythons before 3.9, then any parametrized `dict`, `list`, `tuple`, etc. in your annotations need to be swapped out for `typing.Dict` etc. — or, alternatively, just add `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of your code.
- Since the values of `temporary_dict_antonyms` are always converted to sets after retrieval, you should probably just store sets in the dict in the first place instead.
- In `insert_word_cache_antonyms`, you `strip()` the elements of `values` when the `word` is not in the `dict`, but you don't do it when adding to a pre-existing collection of values; are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I exchanged your `cache_antonyms` code with mine I get an error **Unresolved reference 'word'**

Comment: Also I use the 'strip()' function to remove the leading and trailing spaces from the strings in the first list.  I could move this `strip()` to the function (scraper) that creates this list.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex: I believe the error was caused by a missing `]` in the return type annotation.  Try now.  // Regarding the `strip()`, my point was more that it seems odd and inconsistent to only strip the first batch of values added for a word but not any subsequent batches.

Comment: Why is this correct `cache_antonyms(word: str) -> tuple[bool, Optional[list[str]]]` using `type hints` and this isn't `cache_antonyms(word: str) -> [bool, str]`?

Comment: Because `[bool, str]` simply isn't a valid type annotation; the minilanguage just doesn't work that way.  Or are you asking about a different aspect?

Comment: No, I'm not asking about any different aspect.  I'm just trying to understand `type hints` before I spend days reworking my code to use them.

Comment: For example: You stated do this `temporary_dict_antonyms: dict[str, list[str]] = {}`, but some code website says to do this: `temporary_dict_antonyms: Union[str, list[str]] = {}`.  I'm trying to understand the rules, so that I can implement things correctly myself.

Comment: `Union[str, list[str]]` would mean that `temporary_dict_antonyms` was either a `str` or a list of `str`, which is not right at all for this case.  It's a `dict`, so you need to declare it as `dict[KeyType, ValueType]`; in this case, the `dict` maps `str`s to lists of `str`s, so `dict[str, list[str]]`.

Comment: One last thing on `type hints`.  Can you recommend a good online source, which I can study on implementing these?

Comment: Maybe <https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html>?

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance in understanding this.  Happy Coding!